# In jQuery value is getting but AJAX shows failure?

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter

I am trying to send id of user using AJAX and jQuery to controller from view, but the id is not posting to controller. AJAX script is showing failure in console.

View:

```
<a href="#" id="<?php echo $data['employee_id'];?>" onclick="passid(this)">
    <?php echo $data['employee_name'];?>
</a>
```

AJAX code:

```
function passid(el) {
    var id = el.id;
    console.log(id);
    debugger;

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: "<?=base_url()?>index.php/logincontroller/pass_id",
        data: { "id": id },
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {   // success callback function
            console.log("success");
        },
        error: function (data) { // error callback 
            console.log("fail");
        }
    }); debugger;
}
```

Controller:

```
public function pass_id() {
    $id=$this->input->post('id');
    $this->load->model('user_model');
    $data['profile_data'] = $this->user_model->get_profile($id);
    echo json_encode($data);
    $this->load->view('profile', $data);
}
```

Comment: remove this `$this->load->view('profile',$data);` line from function and check

Comment: it works but how can i load that array values to a view 'profile'?

Comment: through ajax you can't directly. you got data in your success response so you can use that data to update in corresponding part of yout view. If you want to send that data to different view via function then not possible at all

Comment: you can do like this `$view=$this->load->view('profile', $data,TRUE); echo json_encode($view);`